# How to use acronyms in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr-query-syntax, acronym, solr-schema

I use `text_general` field of Solr's provided configuration for storing content of web-pages as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Field:

```
<field name="content" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Say, in `synonyms.txt` I have an entry:

```
ABC=>Apple Ball Company
```

If I perform search on `content` field with `q=content:ABC` On my data where I do not have any content with "`Apple Ball Company`" together.

I get the highlighting-snippets for all words `Apple`, `Ball` and `Company` in my `content` containing those words not in same sequence nor even present together.

I want the highlighting only for the acronym `ABC` and/or only for the expansion "`Apple Ball Company`" (if these words come together in same sequence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are issues with the `SynonymFilterFactory` for multi-word synonyms resulting in "sausagination". It is explained very well here: https://lucidworks.com/2014/07/12/solution-for-multi-term-synonyms-in-lucenesolr-using-the-auto-phrasing-tokenfilter/ The reason is that the filter only takes into account the offset of the tokens but not the position length increment. This has been address with the SynonymGraphFilter, see https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-SynonymGraphFilter

So use the `SynonymGraphFilter` instead of the deprecated `SynonymFilterFactory`, e.g. `<filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonyms.txt"/>`.

Comment: I am getting highlighted results of only `Apple` only `Ball` and only `Company` also iff the same record is having a sequence 'Apple Ball Company`. Thanks @drjz , it worked.